# Is a retract of contractible augmented simplicial complex contractible?

Tags: simplicial-stuff

Suppose the augmented simplicial complex $X$ is a retract of the augmented simplicial complex $Y$ and that $Y$ is contractible.  Is $X$ contractible?  There is an obvious candidate for a contraction, call it $t$ and it satisfies all the required identities except $tt=s^0t$ which I just cannot derive.  On the other hand, it is utterly trivial to see that a retract of a contractible topological space is contractible.